# Feynman Diagrams for a quadratic interaction term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

Consider the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi_{1})^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\chi)^2 - \dfrac{M_1^2}{2}\phi_{1}^2 -\dfrac{M^2_\chi}{2} \chi^2 - \dfrac{\mu_\chi}{2} \phi_1\chi^2 $$

where $\phi_1$ and $\chi$ are real scalar fields. I know that for the above Lagrangian, using only the interaction term $\mathcal{L}_{int} =-\dfrac{M_1^2}{2}\phi_{1}^2$, we recover the Feynman propagator for the 2 pt function $<0 T\lbrace \phi_1(x)\phi_1(y)\rbrace0>$ after summing up all the degenerate Feynman diagrams i.e we get:

$$i\Pi=\dfrac{i}{p^2-M_1^2 +i\epsilon }$$

Now consider the following Lagrangian with an extra massive real scalar field $\phi_2$ and a quadratic mixing term $- M_{12}^2\phi_1\phi_2$,

$$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi_{1})^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi_{2})^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\chi)^2 - \dfrac{M_1^2}{2}\phi_{1}^2 - \dfrac{M_2^2}{2}\phi_{2}^2 - M_{12}^2\phi_1\phi_2 - \dfrac{M^2_\chi}{2} \chi^2 - \dfrac{\mu_\chi}{2} \phi_1\chi^2 $$

In this case, how do I draw and evaluate the Feynman diagrams that contribute to the 2 point function from using only the quadratic term  $- M_{12}^2\phi_1\phi_2$ as an interaction up to order $M^6_{12}$?

How does this differ from the previous Lagrangian and how the propagator will be different now?

Comment: Please show your attempt, and ask about a conceptual difficulty.

Comment: @sammygerbil Please see the question now, I updated it. My problem is with the quadratic term being an interaction, how do I now draw and evaluate the feynman diagrams when I have the quadratic term and eventually by summing up, end up with a propagator? How does it differ to the previous lagrangian?

Answer (score 2):

The Feynman diagram for a term of the form $-M_{12}^2\phi_1\phi_2$ would be a single line coming into a dot and a single line coming out. If the line in is $\phi_1$ the line out is $\phi_2$, and vice-versa. Connecting these up to form higher order diagrams is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the propagator of the $\phi_1$ field is not only from the mass term $\mathcal{L}_{mass} = -\frac{M^2_{1}}{2}\phi_1^2$, but also from the kinetic term:
$\mathcal{L}_{kin} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi_1)^2$. Those are NOT interaction terms. The interaction term is the coupling term between $\phi_1$ and $\chi$ (three-point vertex function).

The quadratic mixing term in the second term between two fields $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ in the second Lagrangian is not the interaction term. It tells us that the mass matrix of the theory is not diagonal yet:
$$\mathcal{L}_{mass} = -\frac{1}{2}M_{ij}\phi_i\phi_j$$
So, we must diagonalise the mass matrix to get the masses of those two fields.

Comment: Yes, but here we are considering the Mass term as an interaction term only for the purpose of the problem. So, in the first case I was able to recover the propagator using that mass term as an interaction term, how should I do something similar but using the quadratic term as interaction term and try to get the propagator again. I know the propagator should be somewhat different to the first case. That's where I am confused how it should be done.

Comment: As an aside, how to get the mass matrix?